# Out of bounds exception Java

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

This code works but it keeps giving me the array out of bounds exception.Even when I change the array size to 6 and leave 2 empty slots at the end it throws the exception. Could someone please identify the problem?

```
  int [] arrayCMYK = new int [4];
  getCMYK(arrayCMYK);

static int getCMYK (int arrayCMYK[])
   {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   //C
   System.out.println("\n\nPlease Enter the 'C' value of the CMYK number.");
   System.out.println("Press Enter after the number has been entered.");
   arrayCMYK[0] = input.nextInt();

   while(arrayCMYK [0] > 100 || arrayCMYK [0] < 0 )
   {
   System.out.println("\n\nError\nPlease Enter the 'C' value of the CMYK number.");
   System.out.println("Press Enter after the number has been entered.");
   arrayCMYK[0] = input.nextInt();
   }
   //M
   System.out.println("\n\nPlease Enter the 'M' value of the CMYK number.");
   System.out.println("Press Enter after the number has been entered.");
   arrayCMYK[1] = input.nextInt();

   while(arrayCMYK [1] > 100 || arrayCMYK [1] < 0 )
   {
   System.out.println("\n\nError\nPlease Enter the 'M' value of the CMYK number.");
   System.out.println("Press Enter after the number has been entered.");
   arrayCMYK[1] = input.nextInt();
   }
   //Y
   System.out.println("\n\nPlease Enter the 'Y' value of the CMYK number.");
   System.out.println("Press Enter after the number has been entered.");
   arrayCMYK[2] = input.nextInt();

   while(arrayCMYK [2] > 100 || arrayCMYK [2] < 0 )
   {
   System.out.println("\n\nError\nPlease Enter the 'Y' value of the CMYK number.");
   System.out.println("Press Enter after the number has been entered.");
   arrayCMYK[2] = input.nextInt();
   }
   // K
   System.out.println("\n\nPlease Enter the 'K' value of the CMYK number.");
   System.out.println("Press Enter after the number has been entered.");
   arrayCMYK[3] = input.nextInt();

   while(arrayCMYK [3] > 100 || arrayCMYK [3] < 0 )
   {
   System.out.println("\n\nError\nPlease Enter the 'K' value of the CMYK number.");
   System.out.println("Press Enter after the number has been entered.");
   arrayCMYK[3] = input.nextInt();
   }
   return arrayCMYK[4];
```

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed. Calling  arrayCMK[4] is actually calling the fifth element

Comment: Apart from the problem you have, that is already solved now, I would suggest you to use `do-while` loop instead of `while` loop, since you want to run the loop at least once. This will avoid the code duplication you are having currently to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are indexed from 0 to n-1, so in your case when you define an array of size 4, you will have indexes 0, 1, 2, and 3. When you `return arrayCMYK[4];`, you are out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you! That was one of the problems but its still returning the same error except now it says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3"

Comment: From the piece of code you've submitted, if you changed the return statement to use index 3, it should not happen. Does the stacktrace perhaps give you an indication of where this might happen? Like a classname, a method name and a line number?

Comment: It says the exception is in the main thread "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at PDispenser_V0.getCMYK(PDispenser_V0.java:220)
 at PDispenser_V0.main(PDispenser_V0.java:50)
" The full thing. But the code I added at the top is the only time I've used arrays or that variable name in the program.

Comment: What is on line 220 of PDispenser_V0? If its the return statement of getCMYK, how is the array passed to getCMYK initialized?

Comment: This is how the return statement is received in the main, not sure if its right?
  int [] arrayCMYK = new int [3];
  arrayCMYK = getCMYK(arrayCMYK);
And nope its not the return statement on line 220 but its " cMYK[3] = input.nextInt(); " By the way, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Now you declare an array with 3 slots, indexed 0, 1 and 2. So 3 is out of bounds. If you want to return the last int you get as input, which would be the one with index 3, you need 'int[] arrayCMYK = new int[4], then you can return arrayCMYK[3], which will be the last available index.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes for an array are zero based so

```
int [] arrayCMYK = new int [4];
```

has indexes 0 - 3

`arrayCMYK[4]` will give you the ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

This index of 4 is out-of-bounds:

```
return arrayCMYK[4];
```

You defined arrayCMYK has an array of 4 integers. Therefore the valid indices are 0, 1, 2 and 3. You access of location 4 is causing the array of out bounds exception.

Comment: You might want to explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
return arrayCMYK[4];
```

You declared an array with 4 elements.
Arrays in Java are zero-indexed.

Thus you can only reference 0-3